# Add context to every Django Admin page

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-views

How do I add extra context to all admin webpages?

I use default Django Admin for my admin part of a site.

Here is an url entry for admin:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

And my apps register their standard view models using:

```
admin.site.register(Tag, TagAdmin)
```

My problem, is that I want to display an extra field in admin template header bar and I have no idea how to add this extra context.

My first bet was adding it in url patterns like below:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls, {'mycontext': '123'}),
]
```

But that gives an error:

```
TypeError at /admin/tickets/event/4/change/

change_view() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mycontext'
```

Can you give any suggestion? I really do not want to modify every AdminModel class I have to insert this context, as I need it on every admin page.

Thanks.

Comment: OP's self-answer did not work for me, possibly because I needed to access the extra data on the admin's `index.html` page -- this is what did work (however superfluous it may be) https://stackoverflow.com/a/40265975/6158303

Answer (score 9):

Found the solution, url registration has to be:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls, {'extra_context': {'mycontext': '123'}}),
]
```

Its a context dictionary inside of a dictionary with `'extra_context'` as a key.

Comment: do you know what view this would get added in, if say I wanted to add a specific queryset?

Comment: After taking your advice (which fixed the problem I was trying to solve very well!) I found that the "change password" form in the Django Admin was broken. This seems like it may be a bug in Django. To get both the extra context and the change password form I had to use Django's ModelAdmin 'add_view' and 'change_view' methods on the individual forms after all. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64072756/706797

Answer (score 5):

Another technique, more complex but allows different context per request (probably unavailable at OP time):

`my_project/admin.py` (create if missing)

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.apps import AdminConfig


class MyAdminConfig(AdminConfig):
    default_site = 'my_project.admin.MyAdminSite'


class MyAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
    def each_context(self, request):
        context = super().each_context(request)
        context.update({
            "whatever": "this is",
            "just a": "dict",
        })
        return context
```

`settings.py`

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'my_project.admin.MyAdminConfig',  # replaces 'django.contrib.admin'
    ...
```

The replace / extend admin class code is taken from [the official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-the-default-admin-site) except this is all in one file.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_project', when I add it in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: @MartinTaleski That looks like a path issue. Be sure to use the directory that holds your `wsgi.py` instead of `my_project`, or create a new module inside the project root and use its name. BTW also thanks for the edit. Dumb me clicked "rollback" by accident, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can monkey-patch the default admin site like so:

Top level `urls.py`:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

...

# Store a reference to the default each_context so we don't cause an infinite loop when we override it.
base_admin_context = admin.site.each_context

def custom_admin_context(request):
    context = base_admin_context(request)
    
    # Do anything we want with the context
    # Example: adding a custom sidebar nav section at the top
    context["available_apps"].insert(
        0,
        {
            "name": "Extra stuff",
            "app_url": "/admin/extra/",
            "has_module_perms": True,
            "models": [
                {
                    "object_name": None,
                    "name": "A custom admin dashboard",
                    "admin_url": "/admin/extra/dashboard",
                }
            ],
        },
    )
    return context

admin.site.each_context = custom_admin_context

...

urlpatterns = [...]
```

If you are already overriding other default admin.site values, this can be a low-complexity solution.