# Custome route in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-tools

I wanted to customize my django admin route

**Not from /admin to something else but to add new clickable custom route inside admin panel**

Currently I have created superuser using `python manage.py createsuperuser` command.
I can login to django admin panel , but what I want is to have a custom route to be displayed in left sidebar or anywhere else after logging into django admin panel. My custom route is like `localhost:8000/my-view/` and my-view should be displayed somewhere in admin panel.

TIA.

Comment: This article can help you to solve this problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49176113/make-new-custom-view-at-django-admin

Comment: Cant you change the route in your urls.py from `path('admin/', admin.site.urls),` to `path('my-view/', admin.site.urls),`.