# Custom Django Admin page loses URLS

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to create a customised django-admin, with a separate page that is referenced in the app_list.

I have used https://stackoverflow.com/a/70446680 as a basis and can obtain the custom admin page.   However, when I return to the admin home, all of the apps in the app_list are lost except the custom one.

I can remedy this by setting `admin_urls = admin.site.get_urls()` but when I do, my custom admin site no longer has a get_app_list method defined (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/56476261), so my app_list in admin, does not show the 'tcptraceroute' app.

```py
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite

class CustomAdminSite(AdminSite):

    def get_urls(self):
        admin_urls = super().get_urls() 
        print(admin_urls)
        custom_urls = [
            path('preferences/', views.my_view()),
        ]
        return custom_urls + admin_urls # custom urls must be at the beginning

    def get(self):
        request.current_app == self.name
        return super().get(request)

    def get_app_list(self, request):
        app_list = super().get_app_list(request)
        app_list += [
            {
                "name": "My Custom App",
                "app_label": "my_test_app",
                # "app_url": "/admin/test_view",
                "models": [
                    {
                        "name": "tcptraceroute",
                        "object_name": tcptraceroute,
                        "admin_url": "/admin/test_view",
                        "view_only": True,
                    }
                ],
            }
        ]
        return app_list

site = CustomAdminSite()
```

I have tried rearranging my app orders in installed apps, and also my urls, which currently load the customadmin site as per:

```
path('admin/', custom_admin.site.urls),
```

It seems that the currently defined admin site class is not accessible via the super() method, in the subclass.
And when I call admin.site.get_urls() in the sub class, the super class no longer has a get_app_list method.

?

MTIA.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that if I set the registry of the custom admin class to the registry of the admin.site then it would work as expected.

Code becomes...

In admin.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from . import views

class CustomAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
    
    def get_urls(self):
        self._registry = admin.site._registry
        admin_urls = super().get_urls() 
        custom_urls = [
            path('preferences/', views.Preferences.as_view(admin=self), name="preferences"),
        ]
        return custom_urls + admin_urls # custom urls must be at the beginning

    def get(self):
        request.current_app == self.name
        return super().get(request)

    def get_app_list(self, request):
        app_list = super().get_app_list(request)
        app_list += [
            {
                "name": "My Custom Preferences App",
                "app_label": "Preferences",
                # "app_url": "/admin/test_view",
                "models": [
                    {
                        "name": "Preferences",
                        "object_name": "preferences",
                        "admin_url": "/admin/preferences",
                        "view_only": True,
                    }
                ],
            }
        ]
        return app_list

site = CustomAdminSite()
```

the view...

```py
class Preferences(views.generic.ListView):
    admin = {}
    def get(self, request):
        ctx = self.admin.each_context(request)
        return render(request, 'admin/preferences/preferences.html', ctx)
```

the template...

```html
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% block content %}
...HELLO WORLD!
{% endblock %}
```