# user_change_password() got an unexpected keyword argument 'extra_context'

Tags: django, django-admin

Django 3.0.7

When I try to change password in admin site, I get

```
TypeError at /admin/auth/user/1/password/
user_change_password() got an unexpected keyword argument 'extra_context'
```

Namely I pressed "this form" link:

[image]

**More details**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/auth/user/1/password/

Django Version: 3.0.7
Python Version: 3.8.0
Installed Applications:
['admin_aux',
 'images.apps.ImagesConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'posts',
 'sidebars',
 'general',
 'categories',
 'marketing',
 'home',
 'authors',
 'taggit',
 'cachalot',
 'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig',
 'widgets',
 'code_samples',
 'hyper_links',
 'polls',
 'applications',
 'videos',
 'quotations',
 'languages',
 'people',
 'arbitrary_htmls.apps.ArbitraryHtmlsConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/pcask/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/pcask/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/pcask/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/pcask/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/pcask/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/pcask/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 231, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/pcask/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/pcask/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 76, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/auth/user/1/password/
Exception Value: user_change_password() got an unexpected keyword argument 'extra_context'
```

How can I localize this problem?

Comment: What is this `admin_aux` app?

Comment: Mainly templatetags and constants for admin site.

I switched it off in settings.py. It didn't help.

Comment: @Michael Is that the complete traceback you have pasted? nothing more?

Comment: Can you try with `DEBUG=True`?

Comment: @tim-mccurrach, the traceback is complete.

Comment: @Bernardo Duarte, DEBUG is already True in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue (though in Django 2.2). It started after I took the advice from another Stack Overflow post on [adding extra_context to every admin page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39476707/706797). This seems harmless, but breaks the "change password" form. In the end I deleted the 'extra_context' changes to urls.py and added the extra_context ONLY to the admin forms I needed using the [ModelAdmin add_view and change_view methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#other-methods).

```
# New Layer Form
def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context={}):
    extra_context['CATALOG_TECHNOLOGY'] = settings.CATALOG_TECHNOLOGY
    return super(LayerAdmin, self).add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)

# Edit Layer Form
def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context={}):
    extra_context['CATALOG_TECHNOLOGY'] = settings.CATALOG_TECHNOLOGY
    return super(LayerAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, extra_context=extra_context)
```

Here are the commits for full context:

- Breaking Commit

  - [urls.py](https://github.com/Ecotrust/marco-portal2/commit/76a669eae3b609c95d4c4381927d3e3554529526#diff-5655813db85da6cb059ed55a5592063e)
- Fixing Commits

  - [urls.py](https://github.com/Ecotrust/marco-portal2/commit/6618c5f35fd7e631000ddb417225e94ffa76eb72)
  - [admin.py](https://github.com/MidAtlanticPortal/mp-data-manager/commit/3f5ae06752933c28141369a39c443592e638455e)

Answer (score 1):

#### What's happening...

I have no idea tbh. It is worth noting a few things though, that the url, should call a method in the User Auth ModelAdmin at `django/contrib/auth/admin` called `user_change_password`. It has the following signature:

```
def user_change_password(self, request, id, form_url=""):
```

which is why the error is being raised, because somehow `extra_context` is being passed to it.

There is also a way for you to change the logged on users password, which does accept a `extra_context` kwarg. My best guess is that one of the apps has overwritten the standard auth `ModelAdmin` and done it not quite right. Certainly everything works fine with a fresh django 3.0.7 project.

> How can I localize this problem?

I would remove all of your additional apps. Hopefully this will fix the problem. If it doesn't then this becomes more interesting. But if it does, I would add them back in one by one until it breaks, and then you'll figure out which additional app is breaking things.

> maybe you even can help me cope with it.

There's a few things I can think of that you could do if you just want to change the password. You can change user details via the shell:

```
python manage.py shell
```

Then the following will enable you to change a password:

```
from auth.models import User
user = User.objects.get(id=1)  # Or whatever user you want
user.set_password('my_new_password')
user.save()
```

This should do the trick. Even easier still, there is a management command that does it (but for this you will need to know the current password). You can simply run:

```
manage.py changepassword *username*
```